# What software are used to make artistic render of plasma?

Tags: modeling

What software can you use to make artistic render of plasma with the cross section of the nuclear fusion reactors? Here are some examples:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HlNfP3iywvI (Helion)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FiNxgdMNGdU (Zap Energy)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k3zcmPmW6dE (General Fusion)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EVlWUQ-UKa4&list=TLGGRqoSMsdmCxsxNzExMjAyMw (TAE)

Comment: Hi. Video questions are generally off topic here.  But FWIW, these could be made using 3D modelling and animation software such as Blender (there's a Blender Stack Exchange) or software such as Autodesk Maya or Cinema 4D.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use Blender https://www.blender.org/

The trick is in the material. You need to use the fresnel node: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/input/fresnel.html

What this does is that returns a value depending on how perpendicular or oblique the surface is versus the light ray to the camera.

[image]

If you use this as a mix-shader you now can add material, for example, white bright, when the angle is oblique and pink when the angle is perpendicular.

You can see that in this screen capture. [image]

Then, when the image is rendered, add a glow filter.

https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=glow+filter+blender

---

In the second video, you have a particle system (after the smoke system) but that is only to make the appearance of trails.

For the material, you simply make a pink strong emitter (that will be blown out as white) and the glow filter I mentioned will make the surrounding zone pink, as a laser blade.

[image]

---

Here is the material. Play with the values of each node. (Click to enlarge)

[image]

Here is the Glow added.

[image]

Here is the render.

[image]

If you want the file I made: https://otake.com.mx/Foros/blender/plasma.zip